# iPhone - Table/Grid Data

Tags: iphone, datagrid, uitableview, uiscrollview

For an iPhone app, I'm going to need to display read-only tabular data in a grid format.  This data could potentially have many rows and columns.

I could use UITableView, but the problem is the data will most likely be very wide and require scrolling.

Is there a way to put a UITableView in a UIScrollView and allow zooming and scolling x and y, but still take advantage of reusable UITableView cells?  I assume putting a huge UITableView in a UIScrollView would not take advantage of the cell reuse (virtualization).

Or am I better off using UIWebView and a HTML table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A webView with HTML tables would likely use more memory, but end up being a lot easier to code and debug than 2D cells inside a tableView inside a scrollView.

Another option for a really large table might be a tiled scrollView where you only render the visible tiles (and release and/or reuse the offscreen tiles).

Comment: I think I am going to compare the performance of each.  Is there an example out there for going the native iPhone route?  HTML should be pretty simple.

Comment: I got it to work natively, wasn't too difficult.  Used an outer UIScrollView for zooming and h-scrolling only, while UITableView handles scrolling vertically.  This allows table cells to be reused effectively.  I was also able to use the header of the UITableView to display a nice "sticky" column header.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a native solution, you might consider this [iOS data grid](http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-data-grid-table-view/586) - even though it's not free, it's quite full featured.